# Find MAX(PK_COLUMN) and display it with corresponding Table Name

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am having 20 tables ( Each table has a `PK` and `data` ), i want to find out what is the current `MAX(PK)` Value for each table.
I Want the result as follows :

```
TABLE_NAME              MAX_VAL
-------------------- ----------
TABELE_A                    114 
TABELE_B                     55 
TABELE_C                     14 
TABELE_D                    866 
TABELE_3                   4552
```

is there any way to accomplish this or else i have to write 20 times `SELECT MAX(PK_COL) FROM TABLE` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your currently connected schema is composed of those twenty tables, and each have identical primary key column name(`pk_col`), then consider the following code block containing an implicit cursor :

```
declare
  v_max pls_integer;
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('table_name    max_val');
  for c in ( select * from user_tables )
  loop
    execute immediate 'select max(pk_col) from '||c.table_name into v_max;
    dbms_output.put_line(c.table_name||'    '||v_max);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

i have found another method which will bring TABLE_NAME,PK_COLUMN and MAX( PK_COLUMN ).

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN RN = 1 THEN
          FORMATTED_QUERY_SET
         ELSE
          FORMATTED_QUERY_SET || ' UNION ALL '
       END AS FORMATTED_QUERY_SET
  FROM (SELECT ' SELECT NVL(MAX( ' || COL.COLUMN_NAME ||
               ' ),0) CURR_MAX_VAL, ''' || TAB.TABLE_NAME ||
               ''' TABLE_NAME,''' || COL.COLUMN_NAME ||
               ''' COLUMN_NAME FROM  ' || TAB.TABLE_NAME AS FORMATTED_QUERY_SET,
               TAB.TABLE_NAME,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TAB.TABLE_NAME DESC) AS RN
          FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS TAB
          JOIN USER_CONS_COLUMNS COL
            ON TAB.TABLE_NAME = COL.TABLE_NAME
          JOIN USER_TAB_COLUMNS COL2
            ON COL.COLUMN_NAME = COL2.COLUMN_NAME
           AND COL.TABLE_NAME = COL2.TABLE_NAME
         WHERE TAB.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'P'
           AND COL.CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE '%_PK'
           AND REGEXP_LIKE(COL2.DATA_TYPE, ('NUMB|INTE')))
 ORDER BY TABLE_NAME;
```

Copy the output returned by the above query and execute.
Note : Remove the last ' UNION ALL ' operator from the query string.
Note : Please correct me if i am doing anything wrong .

Comment: good approach if explicit determination of constraint determination is the case, and the primary key column's name matter. But there's a pitfall need to be noticed that we should consider only numeric primary key columns versus column data type mismatch within a query containing UNION ALL. So I filtered out the other types of columns.

Comment: Btw, we don't need to filter `HAVING COUNT(IDENTITY_COL_NAME) = 1`, since a table can contain only one primary key.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan : Thank you for your great observation.We have some tables with composite PK. So i had to filter it with  HAVING COUNT(IDENTITY_COL_NAME) = 1

Comment: you're welcome, but seems you removed my acceptance :)

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan :Sorry  it was by mistake.